# Permissions on ASPstate stored procedures keep getting deleted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

SQL Server 2012 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

User in the database is ASPState_user. User exists and is in db_datareader, db_datawriter.
A few weeks ago this user lost execute permissions to ALL the dbo.Temp stored procedures. I ran the grant execute for the user on all the dbo.Temp stored procedures. Yesterday those permissions were gone.
Yesterday I created a role db_eceecutor (yea, I hit the e twice, no worries its just a name). I granted execute on all the dbo.Temp stored procedures to the role, added the user to the roll and everything worked for a couple hours. Then the role lost ALL the execute permissions.
This is very confusing - does anyone know why these permissions keep getting deleted? 
I have looked at the SQL Agent jobs and have not found one that deletes these permissions

So what would cause the ASPState database stored procedures to rebuild. All of the problem stored procedures show a create date that corresponds to when the permissions got wacked. Which makes sense to the permission "tree" its a new stored procedure and thus no one would have permissions but the dbo or dbowner role.

Comment: Just throwing this out there... `dbo.Temp` database to me is a development database and could be trashed at any point in time. But everyone is different, so that being said, maybe you can turn on `SQL Profiler` for a few hours, log it to a file and see if the roles are removed as you say.

Comment: Just to be clear these are the stored procedures in the ASPState database
dbo.CreateTempTables
dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
dbo.GetHashCode
dbo.GetMajorVersion
dbo.TempGetAppID
dbo.TempGetStateItem
dbo.TempGetStateItem2
dbo.TempGetStateItem3
dbo.TempGetStateItemExclusive

Comment: There are quite a few more, but I ran out of characters
the ONLY stored procedure that the user retains permissions on is dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions_bkp

SQL Profiler is a no go in my environment. Not enough disk space to save the logs, this is not the only database on this server